# Unable to connect to a MongoDB from Azure synapse

Tags: mongodb, azure-synapse

Unable to connect to a MongoDB from copy activity as a timeout error occurs in just 30 seconds.
The MongoDB seems to be online. I am able to test the connection successfully inside the copy activity. However, when I run the pipeline the following error occurs:

```
A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, 
LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : 
"ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/**serveraddress**:27017" }", 
EndPoint: "Unspecified/**serveraddress**:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", LastUpdateTimestamp: 
"2022-11-18T10:51:01.9853437Z" }, { ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/**serveraddress**:27017" }", EndPoint: 
"Unspecified/**serveraddress**:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2022-11-18T10:51:01.9913438Z" }
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried increasing the tiemout to a higher value ?

[image]